# Change geometry position on mouse click

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, perspectivecamera

I'm a newbie at three.js and i want to place the model where ever i click from the mouse. The problem i'm facing is that i want to convert 2D x,y canvas points into 3D x,y world points (using perspective camera). This may seem like a duplicate but either those answers are now deprecated or they're not exactly what I need.

Here's the JS code that kind of does what I want like it places the geometry at the mouse click but it also changes perspective. I don't want it to do that.

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

document.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);

function onMouseDown(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  var dist = box.position.clone().sub(camera.position).length();

  raycaster.ray.at(dist, box.position);
  console.log(`mouse.x: ${event.clientX} mouse.y: ${event.clientY}`);
}
```

Also here's the Fiddle link of the whole code:
https://jsfiddle.net/2jkhqnty/

P.S : Apologies in advance if I wasn't able to convey my problem correctly and would be grateful if someone could guide me in a direction or give the solution to it. TIA

Comment: Are you trying to place the cube a fixed distance from the camera, or on a fixed plane in 3D space?

Comment: @TheJim01 I'm trying to place the cube a fixed distance from the camera.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it also changes perspective"? The cube is keeping its orientation with respect to the world coordinate system (+x stays aligned with +x, etc.), so your demo is behaving exactly how I would expect it to. Are you trying to make it so the cube always faces the camera? Or is there a different effect you're trying to accomplish? A mock-up picture might help explain it better.